# How do you specify a default for the Django ForeignKey field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I’m trying to add a `ForeignKey` field to a Django model using South. I’m getting the following error:

> ValueError: You cannot add a null=False column without a default value.

I did, in fact, specify a default value for the field, but I’m not sure I did it correctly.

```py
language = models.ForeignKey(Language, default=Language.objects.all()[0])
```

Should this work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AFAIK Django won't execute a QuerySet passed as a param, even if it's limited to one element. You should try something like proposed [in this post](http://djangodays.com/2009/05/11/django-foreign-key-default-value-example/)

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def get_foo():
    return Foo.objects.get_or_create(id=1)

class Bar(models.Model):
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    a = models.ForeignKey(Foo, default=get_foo)
```

Comment: I would post the same. Additionaly you can create a default element in get_foo if Foo has no data.

Comment: Yes, using get_or_create is nice idea!

Comment: This doesn't really work, assuming the only point is to query by something other than `id`. This is because the query is run before the migration is created, and the resulting `id` is hardcoded into the migration. So if anyone who later runs the migration has a different `id` for the desired record, they'll still get your `id` rather than running the query on their database, so will get a random default.

Answer (score 2):

Because `get_or_create` returns a tuple, I think this is a better solution

```
def get_default():
    result, _ = Foo.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
    return result
```

than this

```
return Foo.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really an extension to @radious answer. You can also use lambda in the default, if you're looking to cut out lines of code

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Bar(models.Model):
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    a = models.ForeignKey(Foo, default=lambda: Foo.objects.get_or_create(id=1)[0])
```

note that you have to use index 0 on get_or_create() because the method returns a tuple, so you need to get the object, instead of the tuple.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: Django can't serialize lambda expressions

Comment: The relevance of @HasanIqbal's comment is this means this approach won't work after Django 1.7 (assuming you're using migrations) - [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#serializing-values)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) and [models.ForeignKey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) needs [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) as shown below. *Don't forget to put `.id` just after `get_or_create(id=1)[0]` because [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#default) in `models.ForeignKey()` needs `id` of a `Language` object otherwise there is an error:

```py
language = models.ForeignKey(
    Language,               # Here  
    default=Language.objects.get_or_create(id=1)[0].id),
    on_delete=models.CASCADE # Here
)
```