# Create or get default object in ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have a Model of User. I want to assign new field 'role' to all of these users, Role connects User and his permissions.

Im trying to assign a default role that gives full acess to every existing and every new User, enabling admin to limit someones permissions by creating new Role.

I have looked for possible solutions on Stack Overflow: [How do you specify a default for a Django ForeignKey Model or AdminModel field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937954/how-do-you-specify-a-default-for-a-django-foreignkey-model-or-adminmodel-field/13562197)

but they don't seem to work on Django 3.0.

```
def default_role():
    all_user_permissions = CustomPermission.objects.all().filter(available_for_user=True)
    return Role.objects.get_or_create(name=_("Unlimited"), permissions=all_user_permissions)[0] 


class CustomUser(BaseUser):
...
    role = models.ForeignKey('users.Role', verbose_name=_('role'), related_name='users', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=default_role)


class Role(SafeDeleteTimeStampedModel):

    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(CustomPermission, related_name='roles')

class CustomPermission(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=400, unique=True)

    available_for_users = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

When trying to makemigrations i get:

```
AttributeError: type object 'CustomUser' has no attribute 'default_role'
```

For me it would be better if the method returning default role was inside the class; but then i get the error: default_role() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Please share the `Role` and `CustomPermission` model.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be revelant, but i edited orginal post

Comment: is `default_role` defined in the same file as the `CustomUser`?

Comment: Yes, right above it

Comment: can you share the *full* traceback?